# How can I convert a binary number into a string character using Perl script?

Tags: perl, binary, numbers

How can I convert a binary number into a string character using Perl script?

Comment: A binary what into what form of string?  Give an example of what you have and what you want.

Comment: Please specify the type of string representation you want.  Hex digits?  Decimal digits?

Comment: You are still not getting across what you have and what you want it turned into.  Give a concrete example or we will spend all of our time guessing what you want.

Comment: Any sort of response would be great...

Answer (score 8):

If you mean binary to ASCII like [this](http://www.roubaixinteractive.com/PlayGround/Binary_Conversion/Binary_To_Text.asp) webpage, this should do the trick:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$binarySample = "01010100011001010111001101110100"; # "Test" in binary
$chars = length($binarySample);
@packArray = pack("B$chars",$binarySample);
print "@packArray\n";
```

**output:**

```
Test
```

Answer (score 1):

`chr(0x41)` or `chr(65)` turns the number 65 (41 in hex) into the letter "A", is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Strings can contain either binary data or text characters; nothing special is needed.

Tell us more about what you are trying to do, and that might shed some light on what you mean by "convert" or "binary".